# Xamarin.iOS - Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: xamarin.ios

Since I installed the new version of monotouch (Xamarin.iOS 6.4 [Mono 3.0]), I'm getting the following error when compiling for the simulator:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from: Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libziparchive.a(ZipArchive.o)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

It works fine compiling for device. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild shot, but try to pass `--cxx` to mtouch in the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options.